# When sed is used in an expect command, what is the proper way to escape the backslashes?

Tags: linux, sed, expect

I currently have the following code for an automated ssh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set pw "mypass"
spawn ssh user@login.address.com

expect "Password:"
send "$pw\r"

expect "Verification code:"
send "/usr/local/bin/authtool --totp --base32 $(sed -n '/^secret=/s///p' ~/.Auth.sc)\r"
```

Essentially, I have a two-step procedure for login. First the password (which is working), and secondly the authentication (which isn't).

Every time I get to the sed portion, it returns:

```
can't read "(sed -n '/^secret=/s///p' ~/.Auth.sc)": no such variable
    while executing
```

I am at a loss for what to do, but highly suspect is has to do with the backslashes and escaping them. Am I on the right track?

Comment: are you sure it's the backslashes? I'd recommend updating your title to reflect the actual error message, so that you're not accidentally misleading possible answerers.  It looks to me like `expect` is ... expecting ... a dollar sign to begin a variable, and you expect it to begin a command substitution.

Comment: Reading between the lines, don't you need to run the command `authtool` locally and then send the result as a verification code to the remote login?

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,

Basically in the `expect` script, In this part of the code:

```
send "/usr/local/bin/authtool --totp --base32 $(sed -n '/^secret=/s///p' ~/.Auth.sc)\r"
```

Its treating `$(sed -n '/^secret=/s///p' ~/.Auth.sc)` as an expect variable, which in fact its not.

So try doing this, i.e escaping `$` `(` `)`

```
send "/usr/local/bin/authtool --totp --base32 \$\(sed -n '/^secret=/s///p' ~/.Auth.sc\)\r"
```

Or try using the backticks  .

```
send "/usr/local/bin/authtool --totp --base32 `sed -n '/^secret=/s///p' ~/.Auth.sc`\r"
```

Comment: Or, send the command in "single quotes" and then hit enter: `send {/usr/local/bin/authtool --totp --base32 $(sed -n '/^secret=/s///p' ~/.Auth.sc)}; send "\r"`

Answer (score 2):

In `Tcl`, the `[...]` are equivalent to `$(...)`, so you should be writing your code as:

```
send "/usr/local/bin/authtool --totp --base32 [exec sed -n '/^secret=/s///p' $::env(HOME)/.Auth.sc]\r"
```